# Convert String to INT64

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do I convert in the following code the string to INT64 instead of INT32

```
 public static int TransferClient(string NRIFActual, string NRIFNuevo)
    {
        int nResult = 0;
        try
        { 
            nResult = ws.TransferClient(int.parse(NRIFActual), int.Parse(NRIFNuevo));
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        return nResult;
    }
```

Notice that I need the same variable name because it is used in A web service, is there a way to just convert it to INT64 like the int.parse()?

Comment: What is the string that you are passing to `int.Parse()`?

Comment: If it's either too big or too small, you might want to use `long`, `decimal`, `double` or `BigInteger` instead (depending on your requirements).

Comment: The maximum size for a standard int is `2,147,483,647`. If you want a bigger number, you must use a bigger data size(`long` would be the obvious suggestion) . This will also hold true for your database data type (might need a `bigint` in there)

Comment: The maximum value of int is `2.147.483.647` so if you have 10-digit numbers you could bump into this.

Comment: Btw: without a [mcve] the answer to this question is a bit hard to guess.

Comment: Provide more information about your problem. what is the error ? have you tried debugging ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your `try...catch` block in your method is pointless and exception handlers higher up will not have the necessary stack trace information.  If you're not going to do anything with the exception, it is best to just let it bubble up and not catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you accept 9 numbers and want to change it to be 10 numbers, I'm assuming that you mean that the number is 9 digits in length, and you want it to be 10 digits.

The maximum size of a 32-bit integer is ~2.1 billion. You could use a `long` instead, which is a 64-bit integer with a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to use int64

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain the reason for the downvote so I can improve the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You probably get OverflowException because the value that an int(Int32) can store is between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.

1) Verify that the string input you pass is the correct one.

2) If the users shouldn't insert number this high try to add a validation to the input(text box)

3) If the user will(can) insert bigger numbers you should use a type that can store an higher value -> long(Int64) should be enough(The range is –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807), if not go bigger -> you will find a list with C# types here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

Tip:  use TryParse method instead of Parse(for any type you will use). This method will return a bool that states if the conversion succeeded or failed and the actual conversion in output parameter. This will make the exception handling much easier.

Edit after Hans comment:

To keep the solution simple and not dive in another topics you should do something like this:

```
string input = "92233720368547758071";
long result;
if (!long.TryParse(input , out result))
     /*error handling */
else
    /*Continue the flow of your program*/
```

*The input may came from anywhere. This is just for example purpose.

Comment: Could you write an example on how to convert to (int64) in a line? because the code has the variable name fixed in a lines as int.Parse(NRIFActual)